# is it possible to export classes that are on C++ dll?

Tags: visual-c++

I have some C++ project that i writing as dll - ( unmanaged code - not cli ) 
I want to create some class and export this class to other project that will import this dll

Is it possible ? 
How to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, you have several alternatives:

- In your project, you can simply create a [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/adding-references-in-visual-cpp-projects?view=vs-2017) to another project.  I think this is probably the option you're looking for.
- You can also use a [.DEF file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-def-files?view=vs-2017) or add a [__declspec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-declspec-dllexport?view=vs-2017) in your code (or better, in a header file).  You just need to make sure the .dll is in your runtime %PATH% when you execute your program.